# How do I disable smartd permanently?

Tags: xubuntu, services, smart

I installed smartmontools so that I can use `smartctl` occasionally. However, smartd is also part of smartmontools, and now it starts automatically but I don't need it.

What's the proper way to disable smartd permanently?

I'm using Xubuntu 15.10.